# 3d surface plot with function call

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d

I'd like to do a surface plot where z is a call to the pwr.t.test function evaluated at x an y

```
d = rep( seq(.05,.1,.01), length(seq(.2,.26,.01)) )
s = rep(seq(.2,.26,.01), length(seq(.05,.1,.01)))
M =mesh(d,s)
surf3D(x = M$x,
       y = M$y,
       z = pwr.t.test(d=M$x/M$y,power=.8,sig.level=.1,type="two.sample",alternative="two.sided")$n        ,
       colkey=FALSE,
       bty="b2",
       main="test")
```

how can that be done?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the chosen function has a value at the corners of your rectangle of `x` and `y`? (If this `pwr.t.test` is from the pwr package, it doesn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to plot required sample sizes, a 3D plot may be a bit of overkill. So, here first is an approach to just making a 2D heatmap.

First, set your X and Y values. Note that these do not have to be entered multiple times (e.g. with `rep`)

```
x <- seq(.05,.1,.01)
y <- seq(.2,.26,.01)
```

Then, we can create a custom function to calculate the needed sample size for each combination (using `outer`). Of note: the effect size you had calculated before is not correct. Effect size is `{mean(y) - mean(x) } / {sd(x)}` (the `sd` should/could include y; see [here](https://www.leeds.ac.uk/educol/documents/00002182.htm) for more on effect sizes). So, here, I am assuming that your standard deviation is 1, though I noted where you can put that. The `pwr` functions also don't appear to like playing with vectors, so I am looping over each value individually.

```
getN <- function(x,y){
  sapply(1:length(x), function(idx){
    pwr::pwr.t.test(d= (y[idx] - x[idx] ) # / SD???
                    , power=.8, sig.level=.1
                    , type="two.sample", alternative="two.sided"
    )$n
  })
}
```

Then, use `outer` to calculate the sample sizes for each combination. I also like to set the row/column names to help keep track of things

```
z <- outer(x, y, getN)
row.names(z) <- x
colnames(z) <- y
```

gives

```
           0.2      0.21     0.22     0.23     0.24     0.25     0.26
0.05  550.2098  483.6650 428.5144 382.2977 343.1846 309.7905 281.0524
0.06  631.5180  550.2098 483.6650 428.5144 382.2977 343.1846 309.7905
0.07  732.3030  631.5180 550.2098 483.6650 428.5144 382.2977 343.1846
0.08  859.3212  732.3030 631.5180 550.2098 483.6650 428.5144 382.2977
0.09 1022.5344  859.3212 732.3030 631.5180 550.2098 483.6650 428.5144
0.1  1237.1243 1022.5344 859.3212 732.3030 631.5180 550.2098 483.6650
```

Which is the matrix that I believe you want to plot.

Here, I am using `dplyr` to turn it into long format and pass it in to `ggplot` (and using `viridis` for a nice color palette, though others work fine as well)

```
data.frame(z, check.names = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(xVal = row.names(.)) %>%
  gather(yVal, `Sample Size`, -xVal) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(x = xVal
        , y = yVal
        , fill = `Sample Size`)) +
  geom_tile() +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis()
```

gives

[image]

Now, if you really want a 3D version, you can use `plotly` to accomplish that:

```
plot_ly(
  x = x
  , y = y
  , z = z
  , type = 'surface')
```

gives

[image]

And note that the produced version is interactive.

Or with `plot3D`:

```
M <- mesh(x,y)

surf3D(
  x = M$x
  , y = M$y
  , z = z
)
```

gives

[image]

And note that `M` is now much smaller because it is not unneccesarily duplicated.